# Composition of prolongations of $\Gamma$-spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, kan-extension

Let $S,T:\Gamma^{\text{op}}\to \mathsf{Top}_*$ be two $\Gamma$-spaces ($\Gamma^{\text{op}}$ being the category of finite based sets $r_+=\{*,1,\dotsc,r\}$ with based maps as morphisms. The “op” has historical reasons). We can build their prolongations
$$\hat{T}X = \left.\raise0.5ex\hbox{$\displaystyle \bigvee_{r\ge 0}T(r_+)\wedge X^{r_+}$} \right/\lower0.5ex\hbox{$(f^*a,x)\sim (a,f_*x)$}$$
and analogously $\hat{S}$, obtaining two functors $\hat{S},\hat{T}:\mathsf{Top}_*\to \mathsf{Top}_*$ My question now is: Is their composition $\hat{T}\circ\hat{S}$ again a prolongation, namely of $r_+\mapsto (\hat{T}S)(r_+)$?

In other words: Does $\hat{T}$ preserve the left Kan extension $\hat{S}$? (In general, $\hat{T}$ does not have to be left adjoint)

Comment: What is $\Gamma$ here?? Are these standar notation.. if not please explain the notation

Comment: Thanks for the comment; I’ve now added the definition.

Comment: For $T = \Gamma(n_+, -)$ and $S = H\mathbb{Z}$ I believe we have $\tilde{T}(\tilde{S}(X)) \cong \mathbb{Z}[X]^n$, whereas $(\tilde{T}S)(X)\cong (\mathbb{Z}^n)[X]$, so it wouldn't be true on the nose. (Here $A[X]$ denotes the reduced $A$-linearization of the based space $X$.) Maybe its worthwhile to have a look at Lydakis' "Smash products and $\Gamma$-spaces" where, for instance, it is proven in Proposition 5.23 that there is a stable equivalence of $\Gamma$-spaces:  $T\wedge S\rightarrow \tilde{T}\circ S$.